# ANTLR 4 extraneous input matching non lexer item

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar like this :

```
grammar MyGrammar;

field  : f1 (STROKE f2 f3)? ;

f1 : FIELDTEXT+ ;
f2 : 'A' ;
f3 : NUMBER4 ; 

FIELDTEXT    : ~['/'] ;
NUMBER4  : [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9];
STROKE : '/' ;
```

This works well enough, and fields `f1 f2 f3` are all populated correctly.

Except when there is an `A` to the left of the `/`, (regardless of the presence of the optional part) this additionally causes an error:

```
extraneous input 'A' expecting {<EOF>, FIELDTEXT, '/'}
```

Some sample Data:

```
PHOEN
```

-> OK.

```
KLM405/A4046
```

-> OK.

```
SAW502A
```

-> Not OK, 'A' is in f1.

```
BAW617/A5136
```

-> Not OK, 'A' is in f1.

I am not understanding why 'A' is a problem here (the fields are still populated).

Comment: Please give the input you are parsing.

Comment: @BernardK - inputs added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `SAW502A` is that 'A' is a separate token, implicitly defined :

```
f2 : 'A' ;
```

(it would be the same if it were explicitly defined) :

```
[@16,19:19='S',<FIELDTEXT>,3:0]
[@17,20:20='A',<'A'>,3:1]
[@18,21:21='W',<FIELDTEXT>,3:2]
[@19,22:22='5',<FIELDTEXT>,3:3]
[@20,23:23='0',<FIELDTEXT>,3:4]
[@21,24:24='2',<FIELDTEXT>,3:5]
[@22,25:25='A',<'A'>,3:6]
[@23,26:26='\n',<FIELDTEXT>,3:7]
```

and the rule `f1` does not allow anything else than `FIELDTEXT`.
It works with :

```
f1 : ( FIELDTEXT | 'A' )+ ;
```

File `Question.g4` :

```
grammar Question;

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 2305");}
    : line+ EOF
    ;
line
    : f1 (STROKE f2 f3)? NL
      {System.out.println("f1=" + $f1.text + " f2=" + $f2.text + " f3=" + $f3.text);}
    ;

f1 : ( FIELDTEXT | 'A' )+ ;
f2 : 'A' ;
f3 : NUMBER4 ; 

NUMBER4   : [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ;
STROKE    : '/' ;
NL        : [\r\n]+ ; // -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
WS        : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
FIELDTEXT : ~[/] ;
```

Input file `t.text` :

```
PHOEN
KLM405/A4046
SAW502A
BAW617/A5136
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics t.text
[@0,0:0='P',<FIELDTEXT>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='H',<FIELDTEXT>,1:1]
[@2,2:2='O',<FIELDTEXT>,1:2]
[@3,3:3='E',<FIELDTEXT>,1:3]
[@4,4:4='N',<FIELDTEXT>,1:4]
[@5,5:5='\n',<NL>,1:5]
[@6,6:6='K',<FIELDTEXT>,2:0]
[@7,7:7='L',<FIELDTEXT>,2:1]
[@8,8:8='M',<FIELDTEXT>,2:2]
[@9,9:9='4',<FIELDTEXT>,2:3]
[@10,10:10='0',<FIELDTEXT>,2:4]
[@11,11:11='5',<FIELDTEXT>,2:5]
[@12,12:12='/',<'/'>,2:6]
[@13,13:13='A',<'A'>,2:7]
[@14,14:17='4046',<NUMBER4>,2:8]
[@15,18:18='\n',<NL>,2:12]
[@16,19:19='S',<FIELDTEXT>,3:0]
[@17,20:20='A',<'A'>,3:1]
[@18,21:21='W',<FIELDTEXT>,3:2]
[@19,22:22='5',<FIELDTEXT>,3:3]
[@20,23:23='0',<FIELDTEXT>,3:4]
[@21,24:24='2',<FIELDTEXT>,3:5]
[@22,25:25='A',<'A'>,3:6]
[@23,26:26='\n',<NL>,3:7]
[@24,27:27='B',<FIELDTEXT>,4:0]
[@25,28:28='A',<'A'>,4:1]
[@26,29:29='W',<FIELDTEXT>,4:2]
[@27,30:30='6',<FIELDTEXT>,4:3]
[@28,31:31='1',<FIELDTEXT>,4:4]
[@29,32:32='7',<FIELDTEXT>,4:5]
[@30,33:33='/',<'/'>,4:6]
[@31,34:34='A',<'A'>,4:7]
[@32,35:38='5136',<NUMBER4>,4:8]
[@33,39:39='\n',<NL>,4:12]
[@34,40:39='<EOF>',<EOF>,5:0]
Question last update 2305
f1=PHOEN f2=null f3=null
f1=KLM405 f2=A f3=4046
f1=SAW502A f2=null f3=null
f1=BAW617 f2=A f3=5136
```

Answer (score 1):

The input `SAW502A` will be tokenized as six `FIELDTEXT`s, followed by one `'A'` token. That's a problem because 'A' tokens aren't allowed at that position - only `FIELDTEXT` tokens are. Clearly you intended `A` to be a `FIELDTEXT` in this context as well (and only be treated differently in the `f2` rule), but the tokenizer doesn't know which kind of token is required by the grammar at a certain point - it only knows the token rules and generates whichever token is the best fit. So whenever it sees an `A`, it generates an `'A'` token.

Note that this also means that whenever it sees four consecutive digits, it generates `NUMBER4` token. So if your input were `SAW5023`, you'd get an error because of an unexpected `NUMBER4` token.

You can fix the issue with the `A` by introducing a `everythingButAStroke` non-terminal rule that can be either a `FIELDTEXT`, an `'A'` or a `NUMBER4`, but this wouldn't solve the `NUMBER4` issue. And whenever you add a new token rule, you add that one to `everythingButAStroke` as well. But that's not a very good solution. For one, it will get less manageable the more token rules you add. And for another, you clearly intended `f1` to be a list of single characters, but now `NUMBER4` tokens, which have four characters, would be there as well, which would be weird and inconsistent.

It seems to me that your whole `field` rule could be a single terminal rule (ideally separated into `fragment`s for readability) instead of using non-terminal rules like this. That way you would have no problems with overlapping terminal rules.

Answer (score 1):

I have often experienced that a negating lexer rule makes it hard to define other lexer rules, so I prefer to avoid them. It seems that a /, if present, is always followed by an A. Therefore I have another solution.

File `Question_x.g4` :

```
grammar Question_x;

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 0112");}
    : line+ EOF
    ;

line
    : f1 ( f2s='/A' f3 )? NL
      { String f2 = _localctx.f2s != null ? _localctx.f2s.getText().substring(1) : null;
        System.out.println("f1=" + $f1.text + " f2=" + f2 + " f3=" + $f3.text);}
    ;

f1 : ALPHANUM | NUMBER4 ;
f3 : NUMBER4 ; 

NUMBER4   : [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ;
ALPHANUM  : [a-zA-Z0-9]+ ;
NL        : [\r\n]+ ; // -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
WS        : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

Input file t.text :

```
PHOEN
KLM405/A4046
SAW502A
BAW617/A5136
SAW5023
1234/A1234
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Question_x question -tokens -diagnostics t.text
[@0,0:4='PHOEN',<ALPHANUM>,1:0]
[@1,5:5='\n',<NL>,1:5]
[@2,6:11='KLM405',<ALPHANUM>,2:0]
[@3,12:13='/A',<'/A'>,2:6]
[@4,14:17='4046',<NUMBER4>,2:8]
[@5,18:18='\n',<NL>,2:12]
[@6,19:25='SAW502A',<ALPHANUM>,3:0]
[@7,26:26='\n',<NL>,3:7]
[@8,27:32='BAW617',<ALPHANUM>,4:0]
[@9,33:34='/A',<'/A'>,4:6]
[@10,35:38='5136',<NUMBER4>,4:8]
[@11,39:39='\n',<NL>,4:12]
[@12,40:46='SAW5023',<ALPHANUM>,5:0]
[@13,47:47='\n',<NL>,5:7]
[@14,48:51='1234',<NUMBER4>,6:0]
[@15,52:53='/A',<'/A'>,6:4]
[@16,54:57='1234',<NUMBER4>,6:6]
[@17,58:58='\n',<NL>,6:10]
[@18,59:58='<EOF>',<EOF>,7:0]
Question last update 0112
f1=PHOEN f2=null f3=null
f1=KLM405 f2=A f3=4046
f1=SAW502A f2=null f3=null
f1=BAW617 f2=A f3=5136
f1=SAW5023 f2=null f3=null
f1=1234 f2=A f3=1234
```