# can an element contain attribute as parsed by parser generated by ANTLR? if so, how?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am following [this tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-and-the-web/) and successfully replicated its behavior except that I am using Antlr 4.7 instead of the 4.5 that the tutorial was using.

I am trying to build a DSL for expense tracker.

Was wondering if each element can have attributes?

E.g. this is what it looks like now

[image]

This is the code for the todo.g4 as seen in https://github.com/simkimsia/learn-antlr-web-js/blob/master/todo.g4

```
grammar todo;

elements
    : (element|emptyLine)* EOF
    ;

element
    : '*' ( ' ' | '\t' )* CONTENT NL+
    ;

emptyLine
    : NL
    ;

NL
    : '\r' | '\n' 
    ;

CONTENT
    : [a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_ \t]*
    ;
```

Meaning to say the element will also have 2 attributes such as amount and payee. To keep it simple, I will have the same sentence structure so to allow parsing to be done more easily.

the format will be `pay [payee] [amount]`

the example is `pay Acme Corp 123,789.45`

so the payee is Acme Corp and the amount is 12378945 as expressed in integers to denote the amount in denominations of cents

another example is `pay Banana Inc 700`

so the payee is Banana Inc and the amount is 70000 as expressed in integers to denote the amount in denominations of cents

I am guessing I need to change the todo.g4 and then re generate the parser.

Can an element have other attributes?
If so, how do I get started?

**UPDATE**

This is my latest attempts ranked with latest updates on top:

I just figured out how to use grun and testRig. Thanks @Raven for that tip.

latest attempt: My latest expense.g4 (only difference from earlier attempt is the regex for payment)

```
grammar expense;

payments: (payment NL)* ;  
payment: PAY receiver amount=NUMBER ;  
receiver: surname=ID (lastname=ID)? ;  

PAY: 'pay' ;
NUMBER: ([0-9]+(','[0-9]+)*)('.'[0-9]*)?;
ID: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ ;
NL: '\n' | '\r\n' ;  
WS: [\t ]+ -> skip ;
```

[image]

Earlier attempt: This is my expense.g4

```
grammar expense;

payments: (payment NL)* ;  
payment: PAY receiver amount=NUMBER ;  
receiver: surname=ID (lastname=ID)? ;  

PAY: 'pay' ;
NUMBER: [0-9]+ (',' [0-9]+)+ ('.' [0-9]+)? ;  
ID: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ ;
NL: '\n' | '\r\n' ;  
WS: [\t ]+ -> skip ;
```

[image]

[image]

Earlier attempt: https://github.com/simkimsia/learn-antlr-web-js/commit/728813ac275a3f2ad16d7f51ce15fcc27d40045b#commitcomment-25127606

Earlier attempt: https://github.com/simkimsia/learn-antlr-web-js/commit/0c32aec6ffb4b4275db86d54e9788058a2ce8759#commitcomment-25125695

Comment: I don't understand all the code, but have an eagle eye for typos. Line 56 : `var tokens = new new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(expenseLexer);` --> two times new, probable cause of error.

Comment: @BernardK Thanks. I have removed the extra new and used the payments function as suggested by Raven. I still see empty array when I tried to console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Situation on October 24. 2017 at 19:00 UTC+1.

Your grammar works perfectly. I made a full test in Java.

File `Expense.g4` :

```
grammar Expense;

payments
@init {System.out.println("Expense last update 1853");}
    : (payment NL)*
    ;

payment
    : PAY receiver amount=NUMBER
      {System.out.println("Payement found " + $amount.text + " to " + $receiver.text);}
    ;

receiver
    : surname=ID (lastname=ID)?
    ; 

PAY    : 'pay' ;
NUMBER : ([0-9]+(','[0-9]+)*)('.'[0-9]*)? ;
ID     : [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ ;
NL     : '\n' | '\r\n' ;  
WS     : [\t ]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ; // keep the spaces (witout spaces ==> paydeltaco98)
```

File `ExpenseMyListener.java` :

```
public class ExpenseMyListener extends ExpenseBaseListener {
    ExpenseParser parser;
    public ExpenseMyListener(ExpenseParser parser) { this.parser = parser; }

    public void exitPayments(ExpenseParser.PaymentsContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(">>> in ExpenseMyListener for paymentsss");
        System.out.println(">>> there are " + ctx.payment().size() + " elements in the list of payments");
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.payment().size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(ctx.payment(i).getText());
        }
    }

    public void exitPayment(ExpenseParser.PaymentContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(">>> in ExpenseMyListener for payment");
        System.out.println(parser.getTokenStream().getText(ctx));
    }
}
```

File `test_expense.java` :

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRFileStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test_expense {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]);
        ExpenseLexer lexer = new ExpenseLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ExpenseParser parser = new ExpenseParser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.payments();
        System.out.println("---parsing ended");
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        ExpenseMyListener my_listener = new ExpenseMyListener(parser);
        System.out.println(">>>> about to walk");
        walker.walk(my_listener, tree);
    }
}
```

Input file `top.text` :

```
pay Acme Corp 123,456
pay Banana Inc 456789.00
pay charlie pte 123,456.89
pay delta co 98
```

Execution :

```
$ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar"
$ alias
alias a4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar'
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
$ a4 Expense.g4 
$ javac Ex*.java
$ javac test_expense.java 
$ grun Expense payments -tokens -diagnostics top.text
[@0,0:2='pay',<'pay'>,1:0]
[@1,3:3=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:3]
[@2,4:7='Acme',<ID>,1:4]
[@3,8:8=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:8]
[@4,9:12='Corp',<ID>,1:9]
...
[@32,90:89='<EOF>',<EOF>,5:0]
Expense last update 1853
Payement found 123,456 to Acme Corp
Payement found 456789.00 to Banana Inc
Payement found 123,456.89 to charlie pte
Payement found 98 to delta co

$ java test_expense top.text 
Expense last update 1853
Payement found 123,456 to Acme Corp
Payement found 456789.00 to Banana Inc
Payement found 123,456.89 to charlie pte
Payement found 98 to delta co
---parsing ended
>>>> about to walk
>>> in ExpenseMyListener for payment
pay Acme Corp 123,456
>>> in ExpenseMyListener for payment
pay Banana Inc 456789.00
>>> in ExpenseMyListener for payment
pay charlie pte 123,456.89
>>> in ExpenseMyListener for payment
pay delta co 98
>>> in ExpenseMyListener for paymentsss
>>> there are 4 elements in the list of payments
payAcmeCorp123,456
payBananaInc456789.00
paycharliepte123,456.89
paydeltaco98
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I prefer that you updated ur answer because I wanted to reward it with a bounty of 100. By the way, I am really new to antlr and DSL in general. My long aim is to build my own expense tracker using my own DSL. After I can do the parsing, what should I do? Should I store the DSL language as it is into a database? or i should store the individual tokens into individual fields in a database?

Comment: No experience with DSL, I will soon read Tomassetti's book. Somewhere you have to write an application. It could be in the `exitPayment` listener rule that you store `receiver` and `amount` to a database, not the tokens, which are mainly used by the parser.

Comment: Thank you. I am in direct contact with Tomassetti and have his book. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want but for the provided examples this grammar should do the job:

```
payments: (payment NL)* ;  
payment: PAY receiver amount=NUMBER ;  
receiver: surname=ID (lastname=ID)? ;  

PAY: 'pay' ;
NUMBER: [0-9]+ (',' [0-9]+)+ ('.' [0-9]+)? ;  
ID: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ ;
NL: '\n' | '\r\n' ;  
WS: [\t ]+ -> skip ;
```

If this is what you were asking for I will add some more explanation if needed...

Comment: how do i test your answer? just replace everything inside todo.g4 with this?

Comment: yep... except the `grammar todo` header

Comment: I did as u suggested. How do I "see" that the parsing is successful? currently, I have this result https://github.com/simkimsia/learn-antlr-web-js/commit/728813ac275a3f2ad16d7f51ce15fcc27d40045b#commitcomment-25127606

Comment: Use the testRig to display the parse tree

Comment: Thanks. your tip on testRig made me realise what BernardK was writing about as well. It helped.

Comment: I giving you a 100 points because your answer helped me a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> I am guessing I need to change the todo.g4 and then re generate the
>   parser.

Of course regenerate after each change. For me it's :

```
$ a4 Question.g4
$ javac Q*.java
$ grun Question elements -tokens -diagnostics t.text
```

where

```
$ alias
alias a4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar'
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
```

The more you describe specific contents, the more you may face ambiguity problems. For example, you have two rules :

```
payment   : 'pay' [payee] [amount]
free_text : ... any character ...
```

Consider the following content :

```
* pay Federico Tomassetti 10 € for the tutorial
```

`* pay Federico Tomassetti 10` is ambiguous and can be matched by the two rules, but it will finally be parsed as free text, because of `€ for the tutorial` which doesn't satisfy `payment`.

If later you change the `payment` rule to accept more info after the amount :

```
payment   : 'pay' [payee] [amount] payment_info
```

the above content will be matched by `payment` (in case of ambiguity ANTLR chooses the first rule). The good news is that ANTLR 4 is very strong to disambiguate, it reads the whole file if necessary.

For ambiguous tokens and precedence rules, read the posts of these last three weeks, a lot have been said.

Mixing Raven's grammar with yours, this is one possible solution :

File `Question.g4`

```
grammar Question;

elements
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 1432");}
    : ( element | emptyLine )* EOF
    ;

element
    : '*' content NL
    ;

content
    : payment   //{System.out.println("Payement found " + $payment.text);}
    | free_text {System.out.println("Free text found " + $free_text.text);}
    ;

payment
    : PAY receiver amount=NUMBER
      {System.out.println("Payement found " + $amount.text + " to " + $receiver.text);}
    ;

receiver
    : surname=WORD ( lastname=WORD )?
    ;  

free_text
    : ( WORD | PAY | NUMBER )+
    ;

emptyLine
    : NL
    ;

PAY    : 'pay' ;
WORD   : LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT | '_' )* ;
NUMBER : DIGIT+ ( ',' DIGIT+ )? ( '.' DIGIT+ )? ;  

NL  : [\r\n]
    | '\r\n' 
    ;
//WS  : [ \t]+ -> skip ; // $payment.text => payAcmeCorp123,789.45
WS  : [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ; // spaces are needed to nicely display $payment.text

fragment DIGIT  : [0-9] ;
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

File `t.text`

```
* play with ANTLR 4
* write a tutorial
* pay Acme Corp 123,789.45
* pay Banana Inc 700
* pay Federico Tomassetti 10 € for the tutorial
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Question elements -tokens -diagnostics t.text
line 5:29 token recognition error at: '€'
[@0,0:0='*',<'*'>,1:0]
[@1,1:1=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:1]
[@2,2:5='play',<WORD>,1:2]
[@3,6:6=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:6]
[@4,7:10='with',<WORD>,1:7]
[@5,11:11=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:11]
[@6,12:16='ANTLR',<WORD>,1:12]
[@7,17:17=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:17]
[@8,18:18='4',<NUMBER>,1:18]
[@9,19:19='\n',<NL>,1:19]
[@10,20:20='*',<'*'>,2:0]
[@11,21:21=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:1]
[@12,22:26='write',<WORD>,2:2]
[@13,27:27=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:7]
[@14,28:28='a',<WORD>,2:8]
[@15,29:29=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:9]
[@16,30:37='tutorial',<WORD>,2:10]
[@17,38:38='\n',<NL>,2:18]
...
[@56,136:135='<EOF>',<EOF>,7:0]
Question last update 1432
Free text found play with ANTLR 4
Free text found write a tutorial
line 3:26 reportAttemptingFullContext d=2 (content), input='pay Acme Corp 123,789.45
'
...
Payement found 700 to Banana Inc
Free text found pay Federico Tomassetti 10  for the tutorial
```

As you can see, the € symbol is not recognized. You may need a `CONTENT` rule similar to `FIELDTEXT` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867306/antlr-4-extraneous-input-matching-non-lexer-item), and then you get into trouble ...

Federico's [Mega tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/) is a good start. For nitty-gritty details, see [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) or the online doc [from www.antlr.org](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/index.md).

Comment: I am using the javascript runtime of antlr 4.7 and I followed tomassetti's tutorial quite strictly. so I use the Parse button to kick start the parsing. Your answer appears to use java runtime? is there a way I can use the javascript runtime instead?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used other targets than Java. You need to remove/replace the `{System.out.println...`. I have added a link to Tomassetti's Mega Tutorial which uses several different target languages.

Comment: I just realise a lot clearer what you were trying to do at the start of your answer.