# Processing lines of file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have some file like this

```
 file alldataset; append next;
 if file.first? do line + "\n";
 if !file.last? do line.indent(2);
 end;
 end;
```

and I am trying to write a ruby program to push any line that comes after a semi colon to a new line. In addition, if a line has a 'do', indent from the 'do' so that the following line is indented by two blanks and any inner 'do' be indented by 4 blanks and so on.

I am very new to Ruby and my code so far is quite away from what I want. This is what I have

```
 def indent(text, num)
   " "*num+" " + text
 end

 doc = File.open('newtext.txt')
 doc.to_a.each do |line|
 if line.downcase =~ /^(file).+(;)/i
   puts line+"\n"
 end
 if line.downcase.include?('do')
  puts indent(line, 2)
 end
end
```

This is the desired output

> ```
> file alldataset;
>   append next;
>   if file.first? do 
>     line + "\n";
>     if !file.last? do
>       line.indent(2);
>     end;
>   end;
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that first chunk Ruby? If so, what's with all the `;` characters?

Comment: To be sure we understand correctly which result you expect, please add the desired output after transforming the given input.

Comment: There's also some bitter irony here in that code that's supposed to indent things properly is not indented properly.

Comment: A parser would be a better solution.

Comment: Can I say that if a line has more than one semicolon, it has to be split at the semicolon(s), independently of its content ? What is the indent then ?

Comment: @BernardK, semi-colon is the natural end of each line. Each line after a semi-colon should be indented by 2 blanks except the line starting with "file". In addition, if a line is inside a 'do' then it takes additional indents to make 4 blanks and the deeper the 'do', the more indents.

Comment: @PJProudhon, your mention of parser actually caught my interest and I want to learn more. All of my search on google so far has produced results on how to parse html and extract texts. Do you have any material or website that I could use to understand how parser can be used for this kind of problem?

Comment: @JohnDoe, I'm actually only learning. But you will find some very valuable piece of information in here, on SO.

Comment: @PJProudhon I have added another answer with an ANTLR grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby there are many ways to do things. So my solution is one among others.

File `t.rb` :

```
def print_indented(p_file, p_indent, p_text)
    p_file.print p_indent
    p_file.puts  p_text
end

    # recursively split the line at semicolon, as long as the rest is not empty
def partition_on_semicolon(p_line, p_answer, p_level)
    puts "in partition_on_semicolon for level #{p_level} p_line=#{p_line} / p_answer=#{p_answer}"
    first_segment, semi, rest = p_line.partition(';')
    p_answer << first_segment + semi
    partition_on_semicolon(rest.lstrip, p_answer, p_level + 1) unless rest.empty?
end

lines = IO.readlines('input.txt')

# Compute initial indentation, the indentation of the first line.
# This is to preserve the spaces which are in the input.
m = lines.first.match(/^( *)(.*)/)
initial_indent = ' ' * m[1].length
# initial_indent = '' # uncomment if the initial indentation needs not to be preserved
puts "initial_indent=<#{initial_indent}> length=#{initial_indent.length}"
level       = 1
indentation = '  '

File.open('newtext.txt', 'w') do | output_file |
    lines.each do | line |
        line        = line.chomp
        line        = line.lstrip # remove trailing spaces
        puts "---<#{line}>"
        next_indent = initial_indent + indentation * (level - 1)

        case
        when line =~ /^file/ && line.count(';') > 1
            level = 1 # restore, remove this if files can be indented
            next_indent = initial_indent + indentation * (level - 1)
            # split in count fragments
            fragments = []
            partition_on_semicolon(line, fragments, 1)
            puts '---fragments :'
            puts fragments.join('/')
            print_indented(output_file, next_indent, fragments.first)

            fragments[1..-1].each do | fragment |
                print_indented(output_file, next_indent + indentation, fragment)
            end

            level += 1
        when line.include?(' do ')
            fragment1, _fdo, fragment2 = line.partition(' do ')
            print_indented(output_file, next_indent, "#{fragment1} do")
            print_indented(output_file, next_indent + indentation, fragment2)
            level += 1
        else
            level -= 1 if line =~ /end;/
            print_indented(output_file, next_indent, line)
        end
    end
end
```

File `input.txt` :

```
 file alldataset; append next; xyz;
 if file.first? do line + "\n";
 if !file.last? do line.indent(2);
 end;
 end;
 file file2; xyz;
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
initial_indent=< > length=1
---<file alldataset; append next; xyz;>
in partition_on_semicolon for level 1 p_line=file alldataset; append next; xyz; / p_answer=[]
in partition_on_semicolon for level 2 p_line=append next; xyz; / p_answer=["file alldataset;"]
in partition_on_semicolon for level 3 p_line=xyz; / p_answer=["file alldataset;", "append next;"]
---fragments :
file alldataset;/append next;/xyz;
---<if file.first? do line + "\n";>
---<if !file.last? do line.indent(2);>
---<end;>
---<end;>
---<file file2; xyz;>
in partition_on_semicolon for level 1 p_line=file file2; xyz; / p_answer=[]
in partition_on_semicolon for level 2 p_line=xyz; / p_answer=["file file2;"]
---fragments :
file file2;/xyz;
---<>
```

Output file `newtext.txt` :

```
 file alldataset;
   append next;
   xyz;
   if file.first? do
     line + "\n";
     if !file.last? do
       line.indent(2);
       end;
     end;
 file file2;
   xyz;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are interested in parsing, here is a quickly made example, just to give you a taste. I have learned Lex/Yacc, Flex/Bison, ANTLR v3 and ANTLR v4. I strongly recommend ANTLR4 which is so powerful. References :

- [the ANTLR site](http://www.antlr.org)
- [The ANTLR mega tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/)
- [the expert book](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference)
- [StackOverflow -> Tags -> antlr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antlr)

The following grammar can parse only the input example you have provided.

File `Question.g4` :

```
grammar Question;

/* Simple grammar example to parse the following code :

    file alldataset; append next; xyz;
    if file.first? do line + "\n";
    if !file.last? do line.indent(2);
    end;
    end;
    file file2; xyz;
*/

start
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 1048");}
    :   file* EOF
    ;

file
    :   FILE ID ';' statement_p*
    ;

statement_p
    :   statement
        {System.out.println("Statement found : " + $statement.text);}
    ;

statement
    :   'append' ID ';'
    |   if_statement
    |   other_statement
    |   'end' ';'
    ;

if_statement
    :   'if' expression 'do' expression ';'
    ;

other_statement
    :   ID ';'
    ;

expression
    :   receiver=( ID | FILE ) '.' method_call # Send
    |   expression '+' expression   # Addition
    |   '!' expression              # Negation
    |   atom                        # An_atom
    ;

method_call
    :   method_name=ID arguments?
    ;

arguments
    :   '(' ( argument ( ',' argument )* )? ')'
    ;

argument
    :   ID | NUMBER
    ;

atom
    :   ID
    |   FILE
    |   STRING
    ;

FILE   : 'file' ;
ID     : LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT | '_' )* ( '?' | '!' )? ;
NUMBER : DIGIT+ ( ',' DIGIT+ )? ( '.' DIGIT+ )? ;
STRING : '"' .*? '"' ;

NL  : ( [\r\n] | '\r\n' ) -> skip ;

WS  : [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;

fragment DIGIT  : [0-9] ;
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

File `input.txt` :

```
 file alldataset; append next; xyz;
 if file.first? do line + "\n";
 if !file.last? do line.indent(2);
 end;
 end;
 file file2; xyz;
```

Execution :

```
$ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar"
$ alias
alias a4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar'
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
$ a4 Question.g4
$ javac Q*.java
$ grun Question start -tokens -diagnostics input.txt 
[@0,0:0=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:0]
[@1,1:4='file',<'file'>,1:1]
[@2,5:5=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:5]
[@3,6:15='alldataset',<ID>,1:6]
[@4,16:16=';',<';'>,1:16]
[@5,17:17=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:17]
[@6,18:23='append',<'append'>,1:18]
[@7,24:24=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:24]
[@8,25:28='next',<ID>,1:25]
[@9,29:29=';',<';'>,1:29]
[@10,30:30=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:30]
[@11,31:33='xyz',<ID>,1:31]
[@12,34:34=';',<';'>,1:34]
[@13,36:36=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:0]
[@14,37:38='if',<'if'>,2:1]
[@15,39:39=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:3]
[@16,40:43='file',<'file'>,2:4]
[@17,44:44='.',<'.'>,2:8]
[@18,45:50='first?',<ID>,2:9]
[@19,51:51=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:15]
[@20,52:53='do',<'do'>,2:16]
[@21,54:54=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:18]
[@22,55:58='line',<ID>,2:19]
[@23,59:59=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:23]
[@24,60:60='+',<'+'>,2:24]
[@25,61:61=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:25]
[@26,62:65='"\n"',<STRING>,2:26]
[@27,66:66=';',<';'>,2:30]
...
[@59,133:132='<EOF>',<EOF>,7:0]
Question last update 1048
Statement found : append next;
Statement found : xyz;
Statement found : if file.first? do line + "\n";
Statement found : if !file.last? do line.indent(2);
Statement found : end;
Statement found : end;
Statement found : xyz;
```

One advantage of ANTLR4 over previous versions or other parser generators is that the code is no longer scattered among the parser rules, but gathered in a separate listener. This is where you do the actual processing, such as producing a new reformatted file. It would be too long to show a complete example. Today you can write the listener in C++, C#, Python and others. As I don't know Java, I have a machinery using Jruby, see [my forum answer](https://forums.pragprog.com/forums/206/topics/11251).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @BernardK, this is very helpful. I will learn more about this. Cheers!

Comment: @BernardK, many thanks for this addition. This is exactly what I need to learn and your answer will definitely be useful to me.

Comment: @PJProudhon [Here a complete Java example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872931/can-an-element-contain-attribute-as-parsed-by-parser-generated-by-antlr-if-so/46916429#46916429) with `1.` a small grammar, `2.` a listener `3.` a program to run the parser and walk the tree, calling events in the listener.

Comment: @BernardK, your example looks like a good base for me to start. Thanks again.